# xpath php 7 versus php 5.6

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

The following code worked fine on PHP 5.6 but does not work on PHP 7.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url); 
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($d);
```

With PHP 7  it seems the statement

```
     $xpath = new DOMXpath($d);
```

fails and I'm not able to do things like.

```
    `$jsonScripts = $xpath->query( '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]' );
```

or

```
$metanodes = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta');
```

I confess that I totally hacked my way to getting the 5.6 version to work so please be gentle.

Thanks Phil

Comment: It may be worth checking that the document has loaded in the first place - check something like echo `$d->saveHTML();` gives you the page you are expecting.

Comment: ```echo $d->saveHTML($html)```       does not show anything

Comment: What does "fails" mean? There have been no changes in PHP 7 that would affect the code you've presented here.

Comment: By fails, I mean there is nothing in $xpath = new DOMXpath($d);   Everything I read said exactly what you say, that nothing changes in PHP 7.  But failing to get it to work I used simple_html_dom.php as a work around.  Thanks for inquiring..